# NSManagedObjectContext with private concurrency type executes block on main thread

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

In iOS5, I have a NSManagedObjectContext which I create with a NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType, like so:

```
self.moc = [[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType] autorelease];
moc.parentContext = rootContext;
```

This executes on the main thread, but if I understand the doc correctly that shouldn't matter, since the MOC gets its own queue, right?

Now, at some point I perform a fetch request, like so:

```
[self.moc performBlockAndWait:^() { // (1)
    NSError* err = nil;

    result = [self.moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&err];

    NSLog(@"%@ %@", [NSThread currentThread], [NSThread isMainThread]?@"MAIN":@"");
}];
```

The invocation (1) is also called on the main thread. But I expect the fetch request inside the block to execute on the private MOC thread. Correct so far?

However, if I check the current thread inside the block, it actually is the main thread! The NSLog prints:

```
<NSThread: 0x6b10780>{name = (null), num = 1} MAIN
```

Checking the thread dump confirms this.

The fetch should NOT be executed on the main thread, because this does occasionally result in a deadlock with some other running code. So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm still not entirely sure about the mechanics here, i.e. how something posted on the context-private queue ends up on the main thread. I suspect it has to do with the performBlockAndWait, which executes the block synchronously. I have rewritten stuff so everything is now done asynchronously, and the block is now executed on its private thread.

Thanks for all suggestions.

Comment: Re-read my answer above. There is no private MOC queue - you never created it. The NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType flag is just telling Core Data HOW you want to use it - it won't create the queue for you. Everything you are doing in your code above is on the main queue.

Comment: I tried to edit the above incorrect info, got timed out. My correction: My information was iOS 4 - sorry for the confusion. In any case I think what's happening is that the MOC is doing the work on its queue, and as a convenience to you is messaging you back on the same the same thread you messaged it. So since you asked it to perform the action and will wait for it (performBlockAndWait), its doing the work on its thread but blocking the main thread. You can log just before and just after this message and note the time difference to test this hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks for that correction. I looked it up in the doc once again, which does clearly state that "The context creates and manages a private queue" when specifying NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType. I suspect that something like you describe is going on. Anyway, it's working correctly now.